# QML Loader ... How to unload or delete a qml page loaded on to Loader element

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I have loaded MyItem.qml as a source component onto Loader element. Now i want to remove or unload that page from Loader element. I tried to set source : "" & sourceComponent : "" , also sourceComponent : "undefined". But it did not work

Comment: Can you show us some code, [where you tried it (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 7):

You should set `sourceComponent = undefined` or `source = ""`.
Usually, I use this code:

```
Loader{
    id: loader
    function show(component) {
        sourceComponent = component;
    }
    function hide(){
        sourceComponent = undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation clearly say that you need to specify undefined instead of null, still, this solved the issue for me :)

Answer (score 4):

You can just set the `active` property to `false` for unload or `true` (default) for loading.

Comment: Such a simple and concise solution. This has become my preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the actual issue was, but in case you ran into errors where the component you're trying to unload is trying to access things it shouldn't, it could be because Loader deletes the item using `deleteLater()`, which means it doesn't get deleted instantly. See this bug report for more info:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60344

Answer (score 0):

For example there is this loader:

```
Loader {
    id: loaderLanguage
}
```

to inactive:

```
loaderLanguage.active= false
```